# pip install exceeding maximum recursion depth

Tags: python, pip

I get an error when running

```
pip install datapkg
```

The error is this:

```
"RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object"
```

Partial traceback:

```
RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object

----------------------------------------
Command /usr/bin/python -c "import setuptools; __file__='/home/okfn/var/srvc/data.staging.wheredoesmymoneygo.org/pyenv/src/wdmmg/build/datapkg/setup.py'; execfile('/home/okfn/var/srvc/data.staging.wheredoesmymoneygo.org/pyenv/src/wdmmg/build/datapkg/setup.py')" install --single-version-externally-managed --record /tmp/pip-dV62d0-record/install-record.txt --install-headers /home/okfn/var/srvc/data.staging.wheredoesmymoneygo.org/pyenv/src/wdmmg/lib/include failed with error code 1
Exception information:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/pip.py", line 252, in main
    self.run(options, args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/pip.py", line 410, in run
    requirement_set.install(install_options)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/pip.py", line 2017, in install
    requirement.install(install_options)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/pip.py", line 1515, in install
    cwd=self.source_dir, filter_stdout=self._filter_install, show_stdout=False)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/pip.py", line 3543, in call_subprocess
    % (command_desc, proc.returncode))
InstallationError: Command /usr/bin/python -c "import setuptools; __file__='/home/okfn/var/srvc/data.staging.wheredoesmymoneygo.org/pyenv/src/wdmmg/build/datapkg/setup.py'; execfile('/home/okfn/var/srvc/data.staging.wheredoesmymoneygo.org/pyenv/src/wdmmg/build/datapkg/setup.py')" install --single-version-externally-managed --record /tmp/pip-dV62d0-record/install-record.txt --install-headers /home/okfn/var/srvc/data.staging.wheredoesmymoneygo.org/pyenv/src/wdmmg/lib/include failed with error code 1
```

I can install other packages okay. Any ideas on how to debug this?

Comment: The usual triage questions: a) what version of datapkg? b) what version of pip? c) did you try other versions of datapkg? Personally I wouldn't debug it, I'd report the issue to the package maintainers via their list.

Comment: Related, unresolved python [bug report](http://bugs.python.org/setuptools/issue40).

Comment: Same question asked [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31273332/pip-install-upgrade-sqlalchemy-gives-maximum-recursion-depth-exceeded/31273772#31273772).

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are trying to install some packages that do have recursive dependencies like `A->B`, `B->C`, `C->A`.

Try to resolve this problem. I do not know any case where a recursive dependency would be acceptable.