# Installing pandas in a python virtual environment using pip causes maximum recursion error

Tags: python, pandas, pip, virtualenv

I'm trying to set up a virtual environment for python on Ubuntu 12.04 without root privileges.  I have a virtual environment set up in `/micehome/jbruce/Documents/Code/Python/IPythonNotebooks/learning_venv` on my system here.  `learning_venv` is the name of the virtual environment I've opted to use.

I set it up by doing the following:

```
pip install --user virtualenv
export PATH=$PATH:/micehome/jbruce/.local/bin
```

navigated to:

```
/micehome/jbruce/Documents/Code/Python/IPythonNotebooks/
```

created and activated the virtual environment with:

```
virtualenv learning_venv
source learning_venv/bin/activate
```

confirmed that the right versions of pip and python were being referenced:

```
which python  // <basepath>/learning_venv/bin/python
which pip  // <basepath>/learning_venv/bin/pip
```

checked what packages were installed initially:

```
ConfigArgParse==0.9.3
Cython==0.20.1
generate-deformation-fields==0.0.0
matplotlib==1.3.1
minc-util==0.1.1
morphology==0.56
nose==1.3.1
Numeric==24.2
numexpr==2.1
numpy===1.9.0.dev-3a4030c
py-minc==0.89.1
pydpiper==1.12
pyminc==0.41
pyparsing==2.0.1
Pyro==3.13
python-dateutil==2.2
python-stuffs==0.1.2
scipy===0.15.0.dev-4f35dac
six==1.6.1
tables==2.2.1
vessel-tracking==0.8.2
wheel==0.24.0
```

These appear to be a bunch of packages which are used at my workplace.  Why does it automatically include these packages?  I've even tried `virtual --no-site-packages learning_venv` but it makes no difference.

Anyway, the problem is when I run `pip install pandas`.  Stack trace:

```
Collecting pandas
  Using cached pandas-0.16.2.tar.gz
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 20, in <module>
      File "/tmp/pip-build-q_IpWD/pandas/setup.py", line 631, in <module>
        **setuptools_kwargs)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/core.py", line 112, in setup
        _setup_distribution = dist = klass(attrs)
      File "/axiom2/projects/software/arch/linux-precise/python/distribute-0.6.28-py2.7.egg/setuptools/dist.py", line 225, in __init__
        _Distribution.__init__(self,attrs)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py", line 287, in __init__
        self.finalize_options()
      File "/axiom2/projects/software/arch/linux-precise/python/distribute-0.6.28-py2.7.egg/setuptools/dist.py", line 257, in finalize_options
        ep.require(installer=self.fetch_build_egg)
      File "/axiom2/projects/software/arch/linux-precise/python/distribute-0.6.28-py2.7.egg/pkg_resources.py", line 2029, in require
        working_set.resolve(self.dist.requires(self.extras),env,installer))
      File "/axiom2/projects/software/arch/linux-precise/python/distribute-0.6.28-py2.7.egg/pkg_resources.py", line 580, in resolve
        dist = best[req.key] = env.best_match(req, self, installer)
      File "/axiom2/projects/software/arch/linux-precise/python/distribute-0.6.28-py2.7.egg/pkg_resources.py", line 825, in best_match
        return self.obtain(req, installer) # try and download/install
      File "/axiom2/projects/software/arch/linux-precise/python/distribute-0.6.28-py2.7.egg/pkg_resources.py", line 837, in obtain
        return installer(requirement)
      File "/axiom2/projects/software/arch/linux-precise/python/distribute-0.6.28-py2.7.egg/setuptools/dist.py", line 272, in fetch_build_egg
        dist = self.__class__({'script_args':['easy_install']})
```

The error from 225 to 272 appears recursively until at the very end of the stack trace, when it changes slightly to:

```
"/axiom2/projects/software/arch/linux-precise/python/distribute-0.6.28-py2.7.egg/setuptools/dist.py", line 225, in __init__
        _Distribution.__init__(self,attrs)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py", line 287, in __init__
        self.finalize_options()
      File "/axiom2/projects/software/arch/linux-precise/python/distribute-0.6.28-py2.7.egg/setuptools/dist.py", line 257, in finalize_options
        ep.require(installer=self.fetch_build_egg)
      File "/axiom2/projects/software/arch/linux-precise/python/distribute-0.6.28-py2.7.egg/pkg_resources.py", line 2029, in require
        working_set.resolve(self.dist.requires(self.extras),env,installer))
      File "/axiom2/projects/software/arch/linux-precise/python/distribute-0.6.28-py2.7.egg/pkg_resources.py", line 579, in resolve
        env = Environment(self.entries)
      File "/axiom2/projects/software/arch/linux-precise/python/distribute-0.6.28-py2.7.egg/pkg_resources.py", line 748, in __init__
        self.scan(search_path)
      File "/axiom2/projects/software/arch/linux-precise/python/distribute-0.6.28-py2.7.egg/pkg_resources.py", line 777, in scan
        for dist in find_distributions(item):
      File "/axiom2/projects/software/arch/linux-precise/python/distribute-0.6.28-py2.7.egg/pkg_resources.py", line 1742, in find_on_path
        path_item, os.path.join(path_item,'EGG-INFO')
      File "/axiom2/projects/software/arch/linux-precise/python/distribute-0.6.28-py2.7.egg/pkg_resources.py", line 2298, in from_filename
        **kw
      File "/axiom2/projects/software/arch/linux-precise/python/distribute-0.6.28-py2.7.egg/pkg_resources.py", line 2140, in from_location
        basename, ext = os.path.splitext(basename)
      File "/micehome/jbruce/Documents/Code/Python/IPythonNotebooks/learning_venv/lib/python2.7/posixpath.py", line 96, in splitext
        return genericpath._splitext(p, sep, altsep, extsep)
      File "/micehome/jbruce/Documents/Code/Python/IPythonNotebooks/learning_venv/lib/python2.7/genericpath.py", line 101, in _splitext
        if p[filenameIndex] != extsep:
    RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded in cmp

    ----------------------------------------
```

Not really sure what's going on here and I've found a few related threads but they haven't helped me.  Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31273332/pip-install-upgrade-sqlalchemy-gives-maximum-recursion-depth-exceeded/31273772#31273772).